# Error: Compile Error: A value cannot be stored to Sensitive_Account__c in type Lead at line 12 column 11

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am having difficulty getting this saved so I can test with this tiny code in the sandbox.

If I can get the test working I can update the message.

I am very very new to this.

Apex Class is

```
public class PopUpAlert
{
public Lead lea;

  public PopUpAlert(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

   Lead lea  = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    lea=[select id, Sensitive_Account__c from Lead where Id=: lea.ID];

  }
  public void setAlertVal(){
     lea. Sensitive_Account__c = true;
     update lea;
  }
}
```

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page standardcontroller=Lead extensions=PopUpAlert 
<apex:form id=frm> 
<apex:actionFunction name=setAlertVal action={!setAlertVal} rerender=frm/>
</apex:form> 
<script type=text/javascript> 
    var msg=FYI test : confidential info;
    function throwalert{
       if ( {!Lead. Sensitive_Account__c} == false)
       {
          alert(msg); setAlertVal();
       }
     }
     window.onload = throwalert; 
</script> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi @CNORMAN703, your code seems to have gotten a bit mangled in the posting process. I've fixed some of the formatting (make sure to use Ctrl-k or `{}` button to achieve code formatting), but you have spacing issues and missing quote marks everywhere. Could you update with your current code?

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: If you're getting an error message, including it helps us help you. If you do share an error message, be sure to copy/paste the entire message **verbatim** (i.e. without changing any of the words) as well as the code that is mentioned in the error message. If the error message mentions ClassX Line 123, you should include line 123, and enough of the surrounding code for someone unfamiliar with your code to be able to understand it. The error message may not make sense to you, but chances are there's someone else here who does understand it.

Answer (score 2):

This error shouldn't, as far as I can tell, be caused by the version of your code that you posted, but it's easy to see how it could be caused by a previous version.

As a note, when you ask a question, it's very important to show a single version of your code with the exact error produced by that version. Seemingly-minor changes to your code can produce radically different behavior and error messages, so being as clear as possible will lead to better results.

Focusing just on the lines of code that are relevant to the error:

```
public class PopUpAlert {
    public Lead lea;

    public void setAlertVal(){
       lea.Sensitive_Account__c = true;
       update lea;
    }
}
```

The error

> Error: Compile Error: A value cannot be stored to Sensitive_Account__c in type Lead

should be produced if you accidentally wrote

```
lead.Sensitive_Account__c = true;
```

because the Apex compiler would see this as a reference to some field `Sensitive_Account__c` *on the class `Lead`*, which you can't write to. It's important to remember that Apex is not case-sensitive.

As written, I would not expect this error to be produced. If `Sensitive_Account__c` is a formula field and therefore non-writeable, you'd get a different error.

There is another issue with your Apex that I'd like to pull out here.

```
public class PopUpAlert {
  public Lead lea;

  public PopUpAlert(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    Lead lea  = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    lea=[select id, Sensitive_Account__c from Lead where Id=: lea.ID];
  }
}
```

In your constructor, you declare another variable `lea`. This declaration *shadows* your instance variable `lea`, meaning that operations inside the constructor apply to its local variable, not the instance variable. As a result, your instance variable is never initialized, and would be `null` if `setAlertVal()` executed - which would produce a `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this, use an explicit instance variable reference with `this`, or name your local variable something different.

```
    Lead lea = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    this.lea = [select id, Sensitive_Account__c from Lead where Id = :lea.ID];
```

Comment: "The error should be produced if the name of your Lead variable here were lead" -  is actually not correct. the following code works just fine as the compiler check for local variables before system classes: `Lead lead = new lead();
lead.FirstName = 'test';
System.debug(lead.Firstname);`

Comment: @Eric I was able to reproduce the OP's error in (what I thought was) the same situation, albeit with a different sObject. Is there any more nuance there i might be missing?

Comment: I do not think so, with the exception of reserved keywords which should be caught at compile time. With that said, I was using execute anon but use this pattern all the time. If you were able to reproduce the error can you post the entire code. I took your class you posted, changed lea to lead and added `lead = new lead();` to the first line in the method, used the first name field and added a debug and it executed without issue....

Comment: I seem to have crossed a wire in the situation I tried to re-create. Instead, it must have been the case that OP actually had an instance variable `Lead lea` but misspelled the reference `Lead.Sensitive_Account__c` in one method. Thank you for the correction.